# How to Authenticate Quickbook REST API using OAuth1.0a.js?

Tags: oauth, quickbooks

I am trying to get some information from quickbook online. I am completely depending on the client side  to get the data. I am using oauth1.0a.js library to create signature, tokens etc. I am confused with the starting point.

As the first step I create a new object with the following information

```
var oauth = new OAuth({
consumer: {
    public: '********',
    secret: '********'
},
signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});
```

Now I have to obtain the following information

```
var oauthdata=oauth.authorize(request,'token');
var sign=oauth.getSignature(request,"token",oauthdata);
```

I am confused over the token aspect. I know only about one token that is app_token which is generated while an app is created from the https://developer.intuit.com. But I need an auth_token to get the data successfully. How to generate this token?

The oauth documentation says that The Consumer obtains an unauthorized Request Token. The User authorizes the Request Token. The Consumer exchanges the Request Token for an Access Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read Intuit's OAuth documentation?

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app

Authentication with Intuit's platform is via [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). The short explanation is:

- You make a HTTPS request to Intuit's servers to get request tokens
- You forward your end-user to Intuit's website to log in
- Intuit sends the user back to you with an oauth_verifier token
- You make another HTTPS request to Intuit's servers to exchange the verifier for access tokens

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Can you please let me know about the menuproxy and granturl. What values are expected there?

Comment: The granturl I specified as the one I have in host name domain from my application profile. The granturl is a php file, which I hope to display the token value returned from quickbook. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: The grant URL is the URL the user would go to to kick off the OAuth process. e.g. if they're not connected, where would they go to connect? The menu proxy URL is a URL which essentially makes a OAuth authenticated request to one of Intuit's URLs which fetches some menu HTML. The menu URL is entirely optional - you don't need the menu at all. Also, PHP libs here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Working PHP app example: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am able to retrieve data from quickbooks using the above php code.

Comment: Hi Keith, I am now trying to retrieve reports. But the request is coming blank. I use the following code $Service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Report_ProfitAndLoss(); and the last response doesn't contain the request url part. In the IPP.php it throws an error showing url is undefined. Please let me know how can I get Profit and Loss account?

Comment: Reports are *really* new to the API - we are working on adding support for them soon.